# There's a ghost code in the boot spring What's the problem?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, web

I'm Java Boots Spring, Maven
In the spring,
We added jpa and Thymereaf as dependencies.
And I ran.

However, the working http://localhost:8080/ was disconnected and an error occurred.
The same was true of other dependencies added.
So I deleted it again from pom.xml.
However, the local host did not work again.

And I found something strange in the class I added.
I annotated it, but it didn't work.
The controller worked after deleting the class code.
Even if I deleted the class, the controller worked.
This is a ghost code.

And this is an added class.

```
/*
package com.team2.crowdfunding.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
@Controller
public class MemberController {
    @GetMapping("/save")
    public String saveForm() {
        return "/user/save";
    }
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String saveForm2() {
        System.out.println("겟 처음");
        return "/index";
    }
}
*/
```

And this is the spring that outputs.

```
 .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.7.5)

2022-11-29 16:01:17.947  INFO 19648 --- [  restartedMain] c.t.c.CrowdfundingApplication            : Starting CrowdfundingApplication using Java 18.0.2.1 on DESKTOP-TMFMLDT with PID 19648 (C:\Users\bitcamp\IdeaProjects\crowdfunding2\target\classes started by bitcamp in C:\Users\bitcamp\IdeaProjects\crowdfunding2)
2022-11-29 16:01:17.948  INFO 19648 --- [  restartedMain] c.t.c.CrowdfundingApplication            : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2022-11-29 16:01:17.988  INFO 19648 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2022-11-29 16:01:17.988  INFO 19648 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2022-11-29 16:01:18.463  WARN 19648 --- [  restartedMain] o.m.s.mapper.ClassPathMapperScanner      : No MyBatis mapper was found in '[com.team2.crowdfunding]' package. Please check your configuration.
2022-11-29 16:01:18.812  INFO 19648 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2022-11-29 16:01:18.821  INFO 19648 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-11-29 16:01:18.821  INFO 19648 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.68]
2022-11-29 16:01:18.994  INFO 19648 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner     : At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
2022-11-29 16:01:18.998  INFO 19648 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-11-29 16:01:18.999  INFO 19648 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1010 ms
2022-11-29 16:01:19.203  INFO 19648 --- [  restartedMain] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : Autowired annotation should only be used on methods with parameters: public org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder com.team2.crowdfunding.controller.UserController.passwordEncoder()
2022-11-29 16:01:19.322  INFO 19648 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.w.s.WelcomePageHandlerMapping    : Adding welcome page: ServletContext resource [/index.html]
2022-11-29 16:01:19.452  INFO 19648 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2022-11-29 16:01:19.483  INFO 19648 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2022-11-29 16:01:19.491  INFO 19648 --- [  restartedMain] c.t.c.CrowdfundingApplication            : Started CrowdfundingApplication in 1.81 seconds (JVM running for 2.124)
2022-11-29 16:01:22.123  INFO 19648 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-11-29 16:01:22.123  INFO 19648 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-11-29 16:01:22.124  INFO 19648 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms
```

What's the problem?

........................

Comment: The problem is that there is far too little information and too vague of a description to answer this.

Comment: I'm sorry. It's my first time asking a question. What information and what should I explain to you? @M.Deinum